# Updating Angular from 12 to 13 causes sass errors when running npm start

Tags: angular, npm, sass, npm-start

I have an Angular app in which I need to update the version from 12.2.6 to 13.4.0.

I've been following the Angular Update Guide here - https://update.angular.io/

After I run the command:

```
ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13
```

everything appears to update fine; my package.json file updates the 12.2.6 references to 13.4.0 references and completes successfully.

The issue I'm having is that then when I try to do an 'npm run start' - which worked fine prior to the updates - I start getting a bunch of errors.

For example, it starts erroring out on the inclusion of a calc( operation in one of the .scss files.

This line in an scss file:

```
margin-top: (calc((#{$--header-height} - #{$img-height}) / 2) - $--header-border-width);
```

Produces this error when trying to run npm run start:

```
SassError: Undefined operation "calc((2.75rem - 2.3375rem) / 2) - 0.075rem".
```

I'm relatively new to updating Angular.  Is the problem that I need to update the code itself to match the new version of angular?

Thanks much.